# Knockout radio button check binding

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

I have ViewModel in which I have array of "Answers".
"Answer" is object that has property 'Selected'. In my demo array I have two Answers. For first Selected=1 and for second Selected=0. I have no idea why both radio buttons are selected.
Here is my demo link - https://jsfiddle.net/jwoscjot/3/
and my binding is

```
<input type="radio"  data-bind=" value: Selected, checked: Selected">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only
>   if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute
>   or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter.

You should consider adding a `selectedAnswerID` property to your view model.

```
<!-- ko foreach: answers -->
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: answerID, checked: $parent.selectedAnswerID">
<!-- /ko -->
```

If you really want to keep the answer's selected state a part of the answer, then you can used the `checkedValue` part of the binding. Note that you won't have a way to "deselect" an answer unless you provide some sort of "clear" button because radio buttons aren't really intended to support multi-select.

```
<!-- ko foreach: answers -->
    <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: selected, checkedValue: 1">
<!-- /ko -->
```